# Python crashing since Spyder upgrade

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have two issues and I'm pretty sure they are directly related.

1)  When I start Python, I see a screen popup for about 2 seconds; it reads Spyder 4.  Then, a moment later my CLI window popups up, and at the top of the window it says Spyder 3.7.  It seems like these are not syncing up, for some bizarre reason.  This is after I ran `pip install --upgrade spyder` in my Anaconda Prompt.  I just noticed this behavior yesterday.

2)  In the past day, I have witnessed Python crashing multiple times.  Before a couple days ago, I have never seen Python crash.

What should I do to get these issues straightened out.

Comment: I _highly_ doubt you're trying to run Python 4. That said, could you add more detail into _how_ you're trying to `start Python`? Is this in the CLI, or an IDE, or some other way?

Comment: @verandaguy I think he means spyder 4 lol

Comment: This is *really* not actionable as-currently-written. "X crashes" isn't detailed enough to know how to run it down. Does it *segfault*? Does it *throw an exception*? If it's happening inside a C module and you attach a debugger, where exactly is it taking place? If the observation is just that two separate symptoms started at the same time, that doesn't necessarily mean they're related -- the same upgrade can cause harmless-side-effect A and fatal-crash B; that doesn't mean the side effect causes the crash.

Comment: ...if it _is_ happening in a C module (which is the easiest way to get an interpreter crash that isn't accompanied by a Python stack trace), then you'll really want to have a toolchain with a C debugger installed, and maybe a debug-symbol-enabled version of the module at hand, to collect enough information to allow the issue to be tracked down. That's not necessarily for the faint-of-heart (on Linux, installing gdb is trivial; on Windows, you can potentially need the exact same version of Visual C++ that the Python version you want to build module debug symbols for was compiled with).

Comment: Whoops, sorry, Spyder 4 and Python 3.7.  LOL.  I guess that's how it works, right.  Anyway, I click the Windows Start button and click a shortcut that points to: C:\Users\ryans\Anaconda3\pythonw.exe C:\Users\ryans\Anaconda3\cwp.py C:\Users\ryans\Anaconda3 C:\Users\ryans\Anaconda3\pythonw.exe C:\Users\ryans\Anaconda3\Scripts\spyder-script.py

Spyder runs fine for about 15-20 minutes, and then the small blue circle starts spinning and Spyder turns light grey, and then I lose all control of it.  I have to cancel it and restart it.  There is no error message that I see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those issues are probably happening because you upgraded Spyder itself, but are using Anaconda to manage all your packages. The Spyder docs recommend never using `pip` to upgrade Spyder unless you *really* know what you're doing, but rather managing it with the `conda` commands.  ([Spyder Docs](https://docs.spyder-ide.org/installation.html))

You should probably just downgrade your Spyder installation, or do a fresh install of the Anaconda library. `pip` can really screw up your packages if you're not careful.

Sidenote, it's worth being more precise with your terminology because the question gets confused. Python is the language, Spyder is the IDE, and Anaconda is the distribution/library manager. So you aren't "starting python" but rather starting Spyder, which then can run Python scripts. Hope that helps!